# what is the best way to update multiple dropdown value of one of the datatable cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

i have data table or table like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>status</th>
         <th>name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><select class="status">
             <option value="100">OPEN</option>
             <option value="100">CLOSE</option>
             <option value="100">PENDING</option>
         </select></td>
         <td>JOHN</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><select class="status">
             <option value="101">OPEN</option>
             <option value="101">CLOSE</option>
             <option value="101">PENDING</option>
         </select></td>
         <td>JACK</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="button" value="Update" id="update"/>
</form>
```

i am using javascript, jquery, spring 4.0.1 MVC framework. here i have to call updateStatus web service call with two parameters upon update button click that includes option value and option text. so first user will change the value in dropdown and when ever user hits Update button i have to do ajax call and have to send those parameters to the controller. if i have 100 rows of data in my table then i just have to send the values that has been changed in that dropdown. could you please tell me what is the best way to do this.Thank You in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/6pL2ejuw/

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to have a jQuery [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event that detects any of the changed select fields. Every time it fires, you store the index of the changed value. Then when the update button is hit, you go through your stored indexes, retrieve their values, and then send it off to your backend. For example:

```
var changeArr = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("select").change(function () {
  var index = $(this).parent().siblings("td.idField").html();
  var value = $(this).val();
  changeArr[index] = value;
 });
 $("#update").click(function () {
  console.log(changeArr);
 });
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwang42/6pL2ejuw/6/

Comment: i kind of tried this but the problem here is: if user change the dropdown value of first td cell and change the value of second row td cell  and then again he decided to change different value for the first dropdown cell then we have duplicates there.

Comment: just to make sure: we have to send basically list of option value and text. eg. option value for first dropdown will be 100 regardless of whatever text value, but text value we have to send is only one.

Comment: Edited my answer, check the fiddle again. Using an associative array, it will now store the index and the associated value of the select box. It will update the value of anytime the user changes the box and not add any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

use code below for your solution

HTML

```
<form>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>status</th>
         <th>name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><select class="status" currentVal="OPEN" newVal="OPEN">
             <option value="100">OPEN</option>
             <option value="100">CLOSE</option>
             <option value="100">PENDING</option>
         </select></td>
         <td>JOHN</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><select class="status" currentVal="OPEN" newVal="OPEN">
             <option value="101">OPEN</option>
             <option value="101">CLOSE</option>
             <option value="101">PENDING</option>
         </select></td>
         <td>JACK</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
    <input type="button" value="update" id="btnUpdate" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(".status").change(function(){
    var newText = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
    $(this).attr("newVal",newText);
});

$("#btnUpdate").click(function(){
    var changedVal = [];
    var allsels = $(".status");
    allsels.each(function (index, selec) {
        var newtext = $(selec).attr("newVal");
        var oldtext = $(selec).attr("currentVal");
        if(newtext != oldtext)
        {
            changedVal.push(newtext);
        }
    });

    //all the changed data will be in "changedVal" array
    alert('make ajax call here');
});
```